# How to solve to setup the printer settings to IE browser?

Tags: c#, printing

I have programmatically setting the default printer settings using C#. The settings are applied to chrome and firefox browsers but where as it is not been applied to IE browser.
Can anyone help me on this ?

```
   var printer = new PrinterSettings();
            var p = new PaperSize();
            p.Width = width.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == cbxPaperSize.SelectedItem.ToString()).Value;
            p.Height = height.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == cbxPaperSize.SelectedItem.ToString()).Value;
            ;
            p.RawKind = rawKind.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == cbxPaperSize.SelectedItem.ToString()).Value;
            ;
            p.PaperName = cbxPaperSize.SelectedItem.ToString();
            printer.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = p;
```

The above printer settings are not set globally. When I try to open the print diloag from IE it is not showing the updated settings like paper size.
[image]

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry , I forgot it . Thanks for reminding.